# Help in Regex - Match YouTube Url

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have the following string for example:

```
abcba"c"bacba"fbaf"gdsfgafa"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eLoApO7wrs"gsg
```

How can I extract the youtube url from this string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"\"(http:[^\"]*)\""
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
\"http://www.youtube.com/watch\?.+\"
```

Comment: Capture the URL in a parenthetic group: `"\"(http://www.youtube.com/watch\?.+)\""`

Answer (score 1):

```
 var  id = Regex.Match(html,@"(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/.+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?
\/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([^""&?\/ ]{11})").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to cover all YouTube URL variants try this:

```
\"(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:(?:(?:www|m(?:usic)?)\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:shorts\/|live\/|v\/|e(?:mbed)?\/|watch(?:\/|\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*v=)|oembed\?url=https?%3A\/\/(?:www|m(?:usic)?)\.youtube\.com\/watch\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*v%3D|attribution_link\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*u=(?:\/|%2F)watch(?:\?|%3F)v(?:=|%3D))?|www\.youtube-nocookie\.com\/embed\/)([\w-]{11})[\?&#]?\S*\"
```

It's a RegExp from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78172756/11194000) for any known YouTube URL (also music.*, shorts/, live/, e/ embed/, v/, *-nocookie etc.). Also catches video ID.

If you want you can restrict the video ID further with [Glenn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988283/11194000) instead of `([\w-]{11})`.