# Validating Youtube URL using Regex

Tags: php, regex, youtube

I'm trying to validate YouTube URLs for my application.

So far I have the following:

```
// Set the youtube URL
$youtube_url = "www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpfzjcCzdtCk";

if (preg_match("/((http\:\/\/){0,}(www\.){0,}(youtube\.com){1} || (youtu\.be){1}(\/watch\?v\=[^\s]){1})/", $youtube_url) == 1)
{
    echo "Valid";
else
{
    echo "Invalid";
}
```

I wish to validate the following variations of Youtube Urls:

- With and without http://
- With and without www.
- With the URLs youtube.com and youtu.be
- Must have /watch?v=
- Must have the unique video string (In the example above "vpfzjcCzdtCk")

However, I don't think I've got my logic right, because for some reason it returns **true** for: `www.youtube.co/watch?v=vpfzjcCzdtCk` (Notice I've written it incorrectly with `.co` and not `.com`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression Youtube URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306963/regular-expression-youtube-url)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are a lot of redundancies in this regular expression of yours (and also, the [leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)). This, though, should produce results:

```
$rx = '~
  ^(?:https?://)?                           # Optional protocol
   (?:www[.])?                              # Optional sub-domain
   (?:youtube[.]com/watch[?]v=|youtu[.]be/) # Mandatory domain name (w/ query string in .com)
   ([^&]{11})                               # Video id of 11 characters as capture group 1
    ~x';

$has_match = preg_match($rx, $url, $matches);

// if matching succeeded, $matches[1] would contain the video ID
```

Some notes:

- use the tilde character `~` as delimiter, to avoid LTS
- use `[.]` instead of `\.` to improve visual legibility and avoid LTS. ("Special" characters - such as the dot `.` - have no effect in character classes (within square brackets))
- to make regular expressions more "readable" you can use the `x` modifier (which has further implications; see [the docs on Pattern modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)), which also allows for comments in regular expressions
- capturing can be suppressed using non-capturing groups: `(?: <pattern> )`. This makes the expression more efficient.

---

Optionally, to extract values from a (more or less complete) URL, you might want to make use of [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$url = 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEOID';
$parts = parse_url($url);
print_r($parts);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => youtube.com
    [path] => /watch
    [query] => v=VIDEOID
)
```

Validating the domain name and extracting the video ID is left as an exercise to the reader.

---

I gave in to the comment war below; thanks to Toni Oriol, the regular expression now works on short (youtu.be) URLs as well.

Comment: Wow, that is an amazing answer.  I think it's going to take some looking at the manual to explain exactly why I works, but it's simply great!  Thanks!

Comment: How to validate youtube link with text box - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735459/how-to-validate-you-tube-url-in-client-side-in-text-box

Comment: doesn't verify the following URL youtu.be/pmpqdwvzzzm

Comment: @muaaz Indeed. Then again, this question is almost four years old. One should expect things to change within periods of this magnitude.

Comment: ohh sorry, I didn't even notice :) anyway, do you or anyone have a modified solution?

Comment: @muaaz That's what "part 2" of this answer is all about. The video ID should be the `path` part of the resulting array. Did you even read this answer?

Comment: No one cares if its 4 years old, or if part 2 is about that (and no, part 2 its about extracting the values). It's simply wrong. I tried to edit to fix it but it seems that it disappeared mysteriously.

Comment: @ToniOriol Your tone... It could be friendlier, friend. Your edit hasn't _magically_ vanished; it simply [failed its review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13818967). And might I ask you the same question as asked before: _Did you even read this answer?_ It says: *The video ID should be the path part of the resulting array.* This case applies even more so when subjecting the `youtu.be/video_id` URL to `parse_url()`: the video ID is _all_ that's in "path".

Comment: Sorry @LinusKleen, i apologize if i offended you. But I could tell you the same: i think my comment is as offensive as you suggesting that @muaaz (and now me) didn't even read your answer.

I'm sorry, but the answer (at least half of it) its wrong. And its not an excuse that the answer is old, the format of the shortened version of the youtube url never included the `/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXXX` it always has been `youtu.be/XXXXXXXXXXX`.

And please, don't get me wrong, i don't want to create a conflict with you here.

Comment: @ToniOriol agreed. Linus is acting confused. Stackoverflow is not "go f*** off and solve it yourself". This answer is wrong, it does not match `https://youtu.be/U4JR1IuKkJM`. Yes, that means i had to figure out myself that the answer is only half a**ed and incomplete, and for me to complete. OKAY LINUS, THANKS ANYWAY.

Comment: oh and a solution is btw this `~
    ^(?:https?://)?              # Optional protocol
     (?:www\.)?                  # Optional subdomain
     (?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)  # Mandatory domain name
     (?:/watch\?v=([^&]+)|/([^\?]+))           # URI with video id as capture group 1
     ~x`
this will save in `matches[1]` (www version) or `matches[2]` (youtu.be version)

Comment: thats right @Toskan, this is exactly how my suggested edit looks like :)

Comment: Nice @LinusKleen :)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to Regular Expressions would be [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
 $parts = parse_url($url);
 if ($parts['host'] == 'youtube.com' && ...) {
   // your code
 }
```

While it is more code, it is more readable and therefore more maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

Please try:

```
// Set the youtube URL
$youtube_url = "www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpfzjcCzdtCk";

if (preg_match("/^((http\:\/\/){0,}(www\.){0,}(youtube\.com){1}|(youtu\.be){1}(\/watch\?v\=[^\s]){1})$/", $youtube_url) == 1)
{
    echo "Valid";
}
else
{
    echo "Invalid";
}
```

You had || which is ok without ^$ in any case.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
$valid = preg_match("/^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/watch\?v\=\w+$/", $youtube_url);
if ($valid) {
    echo "Valid";
} else {
    echo "Invalid";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I defer to the other answers on this page for parsing the URL syntax, but for the **YouTube ID** values themselves, you can be a little bit more specific, as I describe in the following answer on **StackExchange/WebApps**:

> [**Format for ID of YouTube video**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101153/141734)   -    https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/101153/141734
>
> ---
>
> **Video Id**
>
> For the **videoId**, it is an 8-byte (64-bit) integer. Applying Base64-encoding to 8 bytes of data requires **11 characters**. However, since each Base64 character conveys exactly 6 bits, this allocation could actually hold up to `11 × 6 = 66` bits--a surplus of 2 bits over what our payload needs. The excess bits are set to zero, which has the effect of excluding certain characters from ever appearing in the last position of the encoded string. In particular, the **videoId** will always end with one of the following:
>
> ```
> { A, E, I, M, Q, U, Y, c, g, k, o, s, w, 0, 4, 8 }
> ```
>
> Thus, a regular expression (RegEx) for the **videoId** would be as follows:
>
> ```
> [-_A-Za-z0-9]{10}[AEIMQUYcgkosw048]
> ```
>
> **Channel or Playlist Id**
>
> The **channelId** and **playlistId** strings are produced by Base64-encoding a 128-bit (16-byte) binary integer. Again here, calculation per Base64 correctly predicts the observed string length of **22-characters**. In this case, the output is capable of encoding `22 × 6 = 132` bits, a surplus of 4 bits; those zeros end up restricting most of the 64 alphabet symbols from appearing in the last position, and only 4 remain eligible. All **channelId** strings end in one of the following:
>
> ```
> { A, Q, g, w }
> ```
>
> This gives us the regular expression for a **channelId**:
>
> ```
> [-_A-Za-z0-9]{21}[AQgw]
> ```

Comment: Thanks for adding this additional information Glenn!  Therefore a more specific version of the resex would be https://regex101.com/r/pveXvY/1

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to cover all YouTube URL variants try this:

```
^(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:(?:(?:www|m(?:usic)?)\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:shorts\/|live\/|v\/|e(?:mbed)?\/|watch(?:\/|\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*v=)|oembed\?url=https?%3A\/\/(?:www|m(?:usic)?)\.youtube\.com\/watch\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*v%3D|attribution_link\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*u=(?:\/|%2F)watch(?:\?|%3F)v(?:=|%3D))?|www\.youtube-nocookie\.com\/embed\/)([\w-]{11})[\?&#]?\S*$
```

It's a RegExp from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78172756/11194000) for any known YouTube URL (also music.*, shorts/, live/, e/ embed/, v/, *-nocookie etc.). Also catches video ID.

If you want you can restrict the video ID further with [Glenn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988283/11194000) instead of `([\w-]{11})`.