# Regex for youtube URL

Tags: regex, youtube

I am using the following regex for validating youtube video **share** url's.

```
var valid = /^(http\:\/\/)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)+$/;
alert(valid.test(url));
return false;
```

I want the regex to support the following URL formats:

```
http://youtu.be/cCnrX1w5luM  
http://youtube/cCnrX1w5luM  
www.youtube.com/cCnrX1w5luM  
youtube/cCnrX1w5luM  
youtu.be/cCnrX1w5luM
```

I tried different regex but I am not getting a suitable one for share links. Can anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

- You're missing `www` in your regex
- The second `\.` should optional if you want to match both `youtu.be` and `youtube` (but I didn't change this since just `youtube` isn't actually a valid domain - see note below)
- `+` in your regex allows for one or more of `(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)`, not one or more wild-cards.
  You need to use a `.` to indicate a wild-card, and `+` to indicate you want one or more of them.

Try:

```
^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/.+$
```

[Live demo](https://rubular.com/r/KhJl8bYi89ZFNq).

If you want it to match URLs with or without the `www.`, just make it optional:

```
^(https?\:\/\/)?((www\.)?youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/.+$
```

[Live demo](https://rubular.com/r/ZMlV6pzCw9P9TP).

**Invalid alternatives:**

If you want `www.youtu.be/...` to also match (at the time of writing, this doesn't appear to be a valid URL format), put the optional `www.` outside the brackets:

```
^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/.+$
```

`youtube/cCnrX1w5luM` (with or without `http://`) isn't a valid URL, but the question explicitly mentions that the regex should support that. To include this, replace `youtu\.be` with `youtu\.?be` in any regex above. [Live demo](https://rubular.com/r/aDyXFiBpGDC0D6).

Comment: I think the question mark in `youtu\.?be` is wrong: you allways want to have the exact string `youtu.be` in the URL if the URL is indeed is pointing to http(s)://youtu.be.
?

Comment: @TomášPospíšek Edited.

Answer (score 111):

Here's a regex I use to match and capture the important bits of YouTube URLs with video codes:

```
^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube(-nocookie)?\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|live\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$
```

Works with the following URLs:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk&feature=featured
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk
//www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk
www.youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk
https://youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk
http://youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk
//youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk
youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk
http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk
//m.youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk
m.youtube.com/watch?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk

https://www.youtube.com/v/DFYRQ_zQ-gk?fs=1&hl=en_US
http://www.youtube.com/v/DFYRQ_zQ-gk?fs=1&hl=en_US
//www.youtube.com/v/DFYRQ_zQ-gk?fs=1&hl=en_US
www.youtube.com/v/DFYRQ_zQ-gk?fs=1&hl=en_US
youtube.com/v/DFYRQ_zQ-gk?fs=1&hl=en_US

https://www.youtube.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk?autoplay=1
https://www.youtube.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
http://www.youtube.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
//www.youtube.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
www.youtube.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
https://youtube.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
http://youtube.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
//youtube.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
youtube.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk

https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk?autoplay=1
https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
https://youtube-nocookie.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
http://youtube-nocookie.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
//youtube-nocookie.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
youtube-nocookie.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk

https://youtu.be/DFYRQ_zQ-gk?t=120
https://youtu.be/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
http://youtu.be/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
//youtu.be/DFYRQ_zQ-gk
youtu.be/DFYRQ_zQ-gk

https://www.youtube.com/HamdiKickProduction?v=DFYRQ_zQ-gk

https://www.youtube.com/live/sMbxjePPmkw?feature=share
```

The captured groups are:

1. protocol
2. subdomain
3. domain
4. path
5. video code
6. query string

https://regex101.com/r/vHEc61/1

Comment: https://youtube.com/foo_bar- and https://youtube.com/foo_bar and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= are not valid YouTube video URLs, but this regex will match them.

Comment: It doesn't match a valid link like https://www.youtube.com/live/sMbxjePPmkw?feature=share . I have added `|live\/` after `|embed\/` part. **Final regex version**: `^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube(-nocookie)?\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|live\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$`

Comment: This matches `youtuxbe/-` which is not a valid YouTube URL. Changing the regex to `^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube(-nocookie)?\.com|youtu\.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|live\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$` fixes this for me.

Answer (score 20):

I know I'm like 2 years late to the party, but I was needing to write something up anyway, and seems to fit every test case that I can throw at it. Should be able to reference the first match ($1) to get the ID. Matches the http, https, www and non-www, youtube.com, youtu.be, /watch? and /watch.php? on youtube.com (youtu.be does not use these), and it supports matching even when there are other variables in the URL string (?t= for time, ?list= for playlists, etc).

```
(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:www\.|m\.)?youtube\.com\/(?:watch|v|embed)(?:\.php)?(?:\?.*v=|\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\_-]+)
```

Comment: Any chance you could update this to support https://www.youtube.com/watch/IDHERE, which is valid?

Comment: @JacobMorrison Another two years late, but what the hell - updated the code :)

Comment: `^(?:https?:)?(?:\/\/)?(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:www\.|m\.)?youtube\.com\/(?:watch|v|embed)(?:\.php)?(?:\?.*v=|\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\_-]{7,15})(?:[\?&][a-zA-Z0-9\_-]+=[a-zA-Z0-9\_-]+)*$` Improved it a bit so it checks entry starts and ends with url, so things like `extra text youtube.com/embed/DFYRQ_zQ-gk extra text` are not valid. Also added validation id is not less than 7 symbols

Answer (score 12):

Format for YouTube videos has changed. This regex works for all cases:

```
^(http(s)??\:\/\/)?(www\.)?((youtube\.com\/watch\?v=)|(youtu.be\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\-_])+
```

Tests [here](https://regex101.com/r/xCCtQS/3/tests).

Comment: what has changed? phuc77's answer seems better.

Comment: Not all of these tests will pass using phuc77's answer: https://regex101.com/r/RyE7OM/2/tests.
Specifically, https://youtube.com/foo_bar and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= should not validate.

Comment: This answer should be used by anyone searching for a solution. It is the best I've found till now.

Comment: If you wanted to catch the ID, then there's a typo in your regex, the + sign at the end should be before the last parenthesis because otherwise it's going to capture only last letter. The final regex should look like this `^(http(s)??\:\/\/)?(www\.)?((youtube\.com\/watch\?v=)|(youtu.be\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)`

Comment: The phuc77 seems better, this answer doesn't pass all the test : https://regexr.com/4b2fh

Answer (score 5):

Based on so many other regex; this is the best I have got:

```
((http(s)?:\/\/)?)(www\.)?((youtube\.com\/)|(youtu.be\/))[\S]+
```

Test:
http://regexr.com/3bga2

Answer (score 4):

I took one of the answers from here and added support for a few edge cases that I noticed in my dataset. This should work for pretty much any valid url.

`^(?:https?:)?(?:\/\/)?(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:www\.|m\.)?youtube\.com\/(?:watch|v|embed)(?:\.php)?(?:\?.*v=|\/))([a-zA-Z0-9\_-]{7,15})(?:[\?&][a-zA-Z0-9\_-]+=[a-zA-Z0-9\_-]+)*(?:[&\/\#].*)?$`

Comment: This seems to catch all the cases plus it gets the video ID in a separate group

Comment: This works better than any other regex in this thread, Thank @zmanplex

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
((http://)?)(www\.)?((youtube\.com/)|(youtu\.be)|(youtube)).+
```

http://regexr.com?36o7a

Comment: There are a few unnecessary brackets there - `...(youtube\.com/|youtu.be|youtube).*`, and you probably want to escape the `.` in `youtu.be`, and you may want to put the `/` outside (so it's included for `youtu.be` and `youtube`).

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one and it works fine for me.

```
(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:(?:watch)?\?(?:.*&)?v(?:i)?=|(?:embed|v|vi|user)\/))([^\?&\"'<> #]+)
```

You can check here https://regex101.com/r/Kvk0nB/1

Comment: Are you sure that this is working?

Answer (score 1):

https://regexr.com/62kgd

`^((http|https)\:\/\/)?(www\.youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/((watch\?v=)?([a-zA-Z0-9]{11}))(&.*)*$`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPz9zqakRbk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPz9zqakRbk&t=11

http://youtu.be/cCnrX1w5luM&y=12

http://youtu.be/cCnrX1w5luM

http://youtube/cCnrXswsluM

[www.youtube.com/cCnrX1w5luM](http://www.youtube.com/cCnrX1w5luM)

youtube/cCnrX1w5luM

Answer (score 0):

Modified from [phuk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37704433/3342816) using

- capturing `only-token` / using non-capturing groups for all but token
- multi-line with comments `/x` or here `@x` [x(PCRE_EXTENDED)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)
- using `@` as delimiters as to be able to use `/` without escape.
- non-escape on `-` at end of character lists.
  E.g. `[\w-]` not `[\w\-]`

Example at regex101 with an experimental inclusion of `# Possible:  oembed?url=...v=`:

https://regex101.com/r/0pZCmF/1

```php
$yttok_regex = <<<EOR
@^

# Possible: http://
#       https://
#       //
(?:(?:https?:)?//)?

# Possible: www.
#       m.
(?:(?:www|m)\.)?

# Possible: youtube.com
#       youtube-nocookie.com
#       youtu.be
(?:(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com|youtu.be))?

# Possible: /[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+?v=
#       /embed/
#       /v/
(?:/(?:[\w-]+\?v=|embed/|v/)?)?

# TOKEN:    [a-zA-Z0-9_-]
([\w-]+)

# Possible:
#       Anything not space+
(?:\S+)?

# EOF pattern with x(PCRE_EXTENDED) flag:
$@x
EOR;
```

Optionally use:

```
# TOKEN:    [a-zA-Z0-9_-]
([\w-]{11})
```

To match only 11-char long tokens.

Comment: (PS: as SO still refuses to honor 8-char wide tab, the lineup is not as nice as locally, - but hey. They also do what ever they can to mangle up the source, - which used to work. But they clearly hate tabs to eternity and back and would like all code to be non-indented. Likely negative indented just to make it even worse. But hey. Why use letters at all in code - perhaps we should start using emoticons instead. (The code would in many cases be more readable))

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in my scripts:

```
^(?:(?:https?:)?\/\/)?(?:(?:(?:www|m(?:usic)?)\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:shorts\/|live\/|v\/|e(?:mbed)?\/|watch(?:\/|\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*v=)|oembed\?url=https?%3A\/\/(?:www|m(?:usic)?)\.youtube\.com\/watch\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*v%3D|attribution_link\?(?:\S+=\S+&)*u=(?:\/|%2F)watch(?:\?|%3F)v(?:=|%3D))?|www\.youtube-nocookie\.com\/embed\/)([\w-]{11})[\?&#]?\S*$
```

It matches:

```
    various protocols (and lack of one):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E
//www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E
www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E

    and for each protocol
    various domains:
www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E
m.youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E
music.youtube.com/watch?v=OD3F7J2PeYU
youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E
www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/U9t-slLl30E
youtu.be/U9t-slLl30E

    and for each domain (despite -nocookie)
    various paths:
youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E
youtube.com/watch/U9t-slLl30E
youtube.com/v/U9t-slLl30E
youtube.com/embed/U9t-slLl30E
youtube.com/e/U9t-slLl30E
youtube.com/live/9UMxZofMNbA
youtube.com/shorts/gOcxEMJSksg
youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch?v%3DU9t-slLl30E&format=json
youtube.com/attribution_link?a=JdfC0C9V6ZI&u=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DU9t-slLl30E%26feature%3Dshare
youtube.com/attribution_link?a=8g8kPrPIi-ecwIsS&u=/watch%3Fv%3DU9t-slLl30E%26feature%3Dem-uploademail

    and for each path
    various parameters:
youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E
youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E&feature=shared
youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E&t=1m02s
youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E&lc=UgyYsn3aIQWSA19Esi54AaABAg
youtube.com/watch?v=Lo2qQmj0_h4&list=PLmXxqSJJq-yVWpRFGImHYZBQTuBGLjG4t&index=5&pp=iAQB8AUB
    in various order:
youtube.com/watch?feature=shared&v=U9t-slLl30E

    but not these:
(wrong ID)
youtube.com/watch?v=U$t-slLl30E
(too short ID)
youtube.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30&t=10
(wrong or deprecated paths)
youtube.com/GitHub?v=U9t-slLl30E
youtube.com/?v=U9t-slLl30E
youtube.com/?vi=U9t-slLl30E
youtube.com/?feature=player_embedded&v=U9t-slLl30E
youtube.com/watch?vi=U9t-slLl30E
youtube.com/vi/U9t-slLl30E
(www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/ only!)
youtube-nocookie.com/embed/U9t-slLl30E
www.youtube-nocookie.com/watch?v=U9t-slLl30E
http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/v/U9t-slLl30E?version=3&hl=en_US&rel=0
(playlist)
youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmXxqSJJq-yVWpRFGImHYZBQTuBGLjG4t
```

Try it https://regex101.com/r/7upRfP/

Also catches the video ID. If you want you can restrict the video ID further with [Glenn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41988283/11194000) instead of `([\w-]{11})`.

I'll try to keep this updated on gist https://gist.github.com/Kaligula0/1ff5f4e2cf1f351daeca3450f71fdcb5.

Answer (score -5):

Check this pattern instead:

```
r'(?i)(http.//|https.//)*[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+\.\w+'
```