# React.js get Youtube link from a sentence or paragraph and convert it to a link

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, next.js

I've been browsing the net for solutions but the one's I got is always only with when the user only inputs the link and not in a sentence/paragraph.

I want to convert the link of a youtube video (which is currently a string) to a link. for example:

`Watch this it's good! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<YT_ID_HERE>`

to

`Watch this it's good! <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<YT_ID_HERE>">https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<YT_ID_HERE></a>`

I've found one but the problem to that is when the user pasted 2 links.

I'm making a simple chat application for learning purposes. I'm also using the Next.js.

I want a way, plugin or a package to do this but I prefer the "way" cause' I will eventually use the link to generate an iframe and use the link there to embed the video.

EDIT: I want to it to return the original value but with the youtube link/s wrapped in an `<a>` tag.

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377262/regex-for-youtube-url? You need to use the `/gm` flag for multiline

Comment: Sorry. I meant I want it to return the way it is but wrapping to youtube link to an `<a>` tag. `match()` function only returns those that matches the regex but what I want is to return to the the original value but with the youtube link wrapped in an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

`/https:\/\/www.[\/]*[A-z0-9.\/?=<>]*[\s]/gm`

For : `watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<YT_ID_HERE> hello world`

Matches: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<YT_ID_HERE>`

[This is a great regex writing tool](https://regex101.com/)